# Error trying to buy beta application?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android application(My first!) that I'm trying to make available for ~$1. To make sure it works in Play and to let some people test it, I uploaded a beta APK. I can see the store listing now and such. However, whenever I go to buy it, it just says "your order could not be processed".

Am I missing something, or do I just have to wait longer until it *actually* works

Oh wait.. I got this error when trying to buy from my computer:

> Your order was cancelled because you can't buy from yourself.

So... how exactly do I properly install my own application without going through adb?